# in jquery.get for JSONP how to set async false

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am hitting a timing issue with ajax calls in JQuery using jsonp. I need to wait for my server call to return before proceeding further. However in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ there appears to be no place for setting `async`. Here is my code:

```
        what = ZModel;
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var req = $.get( url, qp, function( stuff ) {
            if ( stuff.status == "OK" ) {
                what.metadata[i].model_name = stuff.datarows;
            } else {
                console.log("...LOAD QUERY ERROR: " + stuff.errtext + "; qs: " + thing.qs);
            }
            alert("success in get");
        }, 'jsonp');
        req.error( function() {
            console.log("...LOAD AJAX ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
        });
```

I also tried `$.ajax` but the code does not hit `success`. The manpage states that clearly but I couldn't figure out an alternative.

Is there a different way to accomplish the same?

Thanks

Comment: It is completely impossible to do synchronous JSONP.  You need to correctly use asynchrony.  Consider using promises.

Comment: why are you setting cors support to true for jsonp? why are you changing it at all?

Comment: @SLaks What is the rationale for not allowing non-async for JSONP?

Comment: @SLaks This **is** the answer to the question. Please post it.

Comment: @user1397919 It is not a matter of allowing or not. This is how JSONP works. If you put a `<script>` tag it will load asynchronously (it is impossible to force it to load synchronously). And JSONP dynamically adds `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely impossible to do synchronous JSONP. 
JSONP works by creating a `<script>` tag; the browser does not expose any way to wait for a `<script>` tag.

In addition, SJAX is *never* a good idea; it will freeze the browser until the server replies.

You need to correctly use asynchrony.
Consider using promises.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to block the UI.

Use something like [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) that "greys" the screen until your call finishes.

Answer (score -1):

Use the .ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async:false,
    success:function (data) {
        // Something
    }
});
```

Comment: -1: It is impossible to do synchronous JSONP. Not to mention that `async:false` is depracated.